# Markov semigroups and resolvents, difference of continuity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $(E,d)$ be a locally compact separable metric space. We have a Markov process $X=(\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0},\{P_x\}_{x \in E})$ on $E$. For bounded measurable function $f$ on $E$, we define
\begin{align*}
P_tf(x)&=E_{x}[f(X_t)],\quad t>0,\\
R_{\alpha}f(x)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\alpha t)P_tf(x)\,dt,\quad \alpha>0.
\end{align*}
We assume that for any bounded measurable function $f\colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha>0$, the function $R_{\alpha}f$ is $\lambda$-Hölder  continuous function on $(E,d)$. That is, it holds that
\begin{align*}
|R_{\alpha}f(x)-R_{\alpha}f(y)|\le C\|f\|_{\infty}d(x,y)^{\lambda},\quad x,y \in E
\end{align*}
Here, $\lambda>0$ and $C>0$ are a positive constant independent of $x,y$, and $f$.
We denote by $\|f\|_{\infty}$  the sup-norm of $f$.

**My question**

We assume that  the Markov process $X$ is symmetric with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure $m$.
Under the above conditions, the semigroup $P_tf(x)$ is also Hölder  continuous in $x$?

If the semigroup is ultracontractive in the sense that $P_t(L^1(E,m)) \subset L^{\infty}(E,m)$, for any $t>0$ and $f \in L^2(E,m)$, we can find a bounded measurable function $h\colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $P_tf=R_{1}h$. Therefore, then,  the semigroup $P_tf(x)$ is also Hölder  continuous in $x$.

Without the ultracontractivity, can we prove the Hölder  continuity of $P_tf$?

Comment: What is the dependence of the constant $C$ on the function $f$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you for your comment. We assume that $C=C'\|f\|_{\infty}$, where $C'$ is a constant independent of $f$.